# Move views pager into row data?

Tags: views, paging

I'm working with Drupal 7 and Views 3 to build a simple video player. The view is fields-based, and is set to display one result (video) at a time. I'd like to provide a "Next" link as shown in the attached image, to allow navigation to the next video. Ideally, the Next link would be available in the row with the other field data.

Normally, pager info is at the bottom of a view. I could use CSS and absolute positioning to move the Next link, but the site is responsive, so it would be a lot cleaner to have the Next link appear with other field data.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

[image: views-based video player, one result at a time]

Answer (score 0):

You best bet is to write a small JS script where it will clone the pager's element content into an empty element within that field.

1. Rewrite the field you wish to insert the pager into. Add a span element or whatever you choose.
2. Write a small js script to copy one elemen'ts content to another. Use this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475727/how-to-copy-text-from-one-div-to-another-in-javascript

Comment: thanks or this idea. I'll give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this is what I did:

1. Installed views simple pager (https://drupal.org/project/views_simple_pager)
2. Configured a simple prev / next pager that displays 1 item only
3. Used CSS to absolutely position prev and next links (with background images as arrows) on either side of the video

This seems to work fine for my use case.

[image]